# Can we biject an $L^{1}$ space over a complete measure space to the $L^{1}$ space over the noncomplete measure space?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a measure space $(X, \mathscr{F}, \mu)$, it is simple to construct a complete measure space $(X, \mathscr{G}, \nu)$, which is done by 1) taking $\mathscr{G}$ to be the sigma-field of all sets each of which is the union of a set in $\mathscr{F}$ and a subset of a $\mu$-null set so that 2) $\nu$ is a unique measure defined on $\mathscr{G}$ such that $\nu|_{\mathscr{F}} = \mu$. If $L^{1}(\nu)$ is defined as the set  $\{ \{ g \mid f=g\ \text{a.e.}-\nu \}\mid f: X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}\ \text{is such that}\ \int f dv < +\infty \} $, can we biject $L^{1}(\nu)$ to $L^{1}(\mu)$??

Comment: Yes, given any $\cal G$-measurable function, there exists a $\cal F$-measurable function such that $f=g$ $\nu$-a.e. Prove this first for indicator functions, then simple functions, then positive functions, then any $L^1(\nu)$ function.

Comment: @Shalop, Thanks. Turns out it is that result that I overlooked. If you want, you can post an answer so that this question will not be left unanswered.